# Wedge product of two differentials

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

In Barrett O'Neill's book, here is the question about the wedge product of two differentials.

Let $f$ and $g$ be real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $$df\wedge dg=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\ 
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \\
\end{vmatrix}dxdy$$

Then, show that it implies the alternation rule ($dx\wedge dy=-dx\wedge dy$)

I can show the above equality easily if I use the properties that $dxdx=0$ and $dydy=0$. But it seems like both of these properties were derived from the alternation rule. So, I guess there might be another way to prove the above equality. Is there any hint to prove the above equality that does not use those properties?

Comment: Consider $(f,g)=(x,y)$ and $(f,g)=(y,x)$. Then Jacobian of each one is 1 and -1.

Comment: @SeewooLee, I mean I need the hint to prove the $df\wedge dg=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\ 
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \\
\end{vmatrix}dxdy$ without using the properties that $dxdx=0$ and $dydy=0.$ The alternation rule is easy.

Comment: What definition of wedge product are you using?

Comment: @Dog_69, $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$ and $dg=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dy$ Then I take their wedge product by expanding them into $df\wedge dg = \sum f_ig_jdxdy$ for $1\leq i, j\leq 2$ where $f_1 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $f_2 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, $g_1 = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $g_2 = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$

Comment: That definition doesn't seem to be correct. $f_1g_1dxdy$ for example shouldn't appear.

Comment: @Dog_69, why ???

Comment: Because $df\wedge dg= f_1g_2dx\wedge dy + f_2g_1 dy\wedge dx$ (let suppose that we do not know the relation $dx\wedge dy = - dy\wedge dx$). In general, the wedge product of two $1$- forms is given by (up to scale factors) $$\alpha\wedge\beta(X,Y)= \alpha(X)\beta(Y)-\alpha(Y)\beta(X). $$

Comment: Oh I get what you mean. I think I might have typos here. $df\wedge dg$ should equal $f_1g_1dxdx+ f_1g_2dxdy+f_2g_1dydx+ f_2g_2dydy$. Is it correct this time ?

Comment: But then where is the skew-symmetry??